# Why I can't get the environmental variable with python os.getenv() command

Tags: python, environment-variables, flask-mail

I have set the environmental variables through GUI in Win10. If I run powershell command to display those variables - I can see them.

```
PS C:\Users\ikori> gci env:\MAIL*

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                                                  
MAIL_PASSWORD                  test                                                                                                                                   
MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER            test@test.test                                                                                                                         
MAIL_USERNAME                  test
```

But if I try to print them with python using os.getenv the result is None. Here's my python code:

```
import os    
print(os.getenv('MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'))
print(os.getenv('MAIL_USERNAME'))
print(os.getenv('MAIL_PASSWORD'))
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\> python test.py
None
None
None
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to use the env variables to configure Flask-Mail.

Comment: You checked if they're set in the _same PowerShell window_ you ran the Python script from, right? (If you ran the Python script from a window started before you changed the variables, there's the problem).

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to share the specific PowerShell command you used to display them in the question, too, instead of only providing that command's output; that way we can be sure the command is displaying active variables for that window, not configured variables for as-yet-uncreated future sessions. When we don't know the specific command you're running, we can't be certain that any particular interpretation of its output is correct.

Comment: Edited to add the wps command

Comment: can you please include the screenshot of the Win10 GUI with the variable settings and the version of python you are using?

Comment: We want to be checking the current process's set of variables, not the canonical/master copy. @mrq -- the GUI will show us what's set for _new_ processes, but not what's set for any given existing one.

Comment: @jul.kori What do you get from `echo $Env:MAIL_USERNAME`?

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. I started doubting if all my windows were up to date so I restarted everything and started fresh and now everything is working. I didn't realize it doesn't update automatically. thanks for your suggestion!